# Firebase firestore new line command for lists in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a new line wherever there is a _n in firestore where data is stored as a list. Is there a way to create it on client side in dart or on firebase similar to Strings where you can replace characters like this

```
speaking.title.replaceAll("_n", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the resulted value to the variable

`speaking.title = speaking.title.replaceAll("_n", "\n")`